# The role of the dot in a formula in the purrr:map function

Tags: r, purrr

Two lines of code produce very different results

`map(1:3,~.x+10)`

result:

```
[[1]]
[1] 11

[[2]]
[1] 12

[[3]]
[1] 13
```

`map(1:3,~x+10)`

result:

```
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   11   13
[2,]   12   14

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   11   13
[2,]   12   14

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   11   13
[2,]   12   14
```

Can anyone please explain the role of the dot in the r formula `~.x+10`?

Besides, can anyone please explain the result for `map(1:3,~x+10)`, where there is no dot in front of `x`.

Answer (score 1):

The `.x` references the numbers you want to add 10 to that you specified in the first argument of `map()` (the `1:3`)and thus returns the expected output. In the case of `~x + 10` you are referencing an object `x` (a matrix) in your environment.